# How to approach real analaysis

Tags: reference-request, self-learning, learning

I'm just starting first year in university in Europe and here there there is no Calculus, instead you jump right into Analysis.
The trouble is, for some time I self-studied through US style books and prepared for uni via How to prove it, OCW and such and just started working through Apostol's Calculus and figured I would eventually progress towards some analysis book.
But, I encountered following curriculum in University course:

1. Logic and Sets
2. Functions and Relations
3. Real and Complex fields
4. Limit of a sequence: intro, convergence, number e,Cauchy's criterion of convergence
5. Limit of a function:basic limits, Heine and Cauchy's criterion
6. Continuity: intro, Weierstrass, Intermediate value theorem, Cantor's theorems
7. Derivative: geometrical interpretation, Fermat, Rolle, Lagrange, Cauchy theorems, Taylor's formula
8. Differential of a function
9. Integral
10. Sequences
11. Metric spaces

Now I'm confused. Should I abandon my routine and pick up some analysis books (and if so which one for beginner?) or just continue doing through Apostol and pick up analysis  stuff on the go.
Perhaps there is some other route.
(Note that I've taken some calculus in high school but only computational stuff, barely touched theory).
Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. You seem to be required to take a class in analysis. The above curriculum seems relatively more like "rigorous calculus" than what I'd call an analysis class. The classic intro analysis book, nicknamed "baby Rudin," hits metric spaces in chapter 2. :)

Comment: Apostol volume 1 covers all (or certainly almost all) of this material except metric spaces, so I think your plan is fine.

Comment: I think I get your point. It's about naming. They don't use the word "calculus" so they label it as "analysis" and sell it as real analysis.So I'll just stick with what I'm already doing. Thanks.

Comment: Depending on the 'European language' presumably spoken where you're studying, it might be just a question of different terminology / 'false friends'. (For example, I have never seen a good translation for the English word 'calculus' in my native language, so I guess that's why it's all 'analysis' here. The contents of such courses tend to be "calculus with theory", and similar to your description.)